# C# - WPF - Mousemove event on canvas will overload the mouse events so click event is not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouseevent

I use Shapes and Canvas, I want to make something like a mapeditor. When the mouse move over the canvas I draw the actually selected object to the canvas at the mouse position on every move, so who use the program can see how it will look like if the object is placed there.

And on mouse click I add the current object/position  to a list, which contains the placed elements which need to be drawn on the canvas in every update.

The problem is if the mouse move handler is active (binded to canvas) then the click event is not fired alway, I need to click continuously For about ten clicks to place the element. If the mouse move event is not binded then the click works perfectly.

I made a GIF to demonstrate my problem.

**Here is when the mouse move event is used**
[image]

**and here is when not**
[image]

I think it's because the move event oveload the event handling, and there is no resource to run the click event.

How I could use the two event together?

**EDIT**

As advised, I attach some code to the example.

I have a model for the canvas named `mapEditorModel`. The property which is important to us is the `mapEditorModel.MapObjects` which is a list containing the elements need to be drawed to the canvas.

The list contains a wrapper object, its contains a lot of information about the elment, which is important to us is that it contains the prebuild shape for draw.

I have a function which is draw the elments on the canvas:

```
private void DrawElementOnCanvas(MapElementContainer item)
    {
        Rectangle shape = item.Shape;

        CanvasElement.Children.Add(shape);
        Canvas.SetLeft(shape, item.Position.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(shape, item.Position.Y);    
    }
```

And I have an `updateCanvas()` method like this:

```
private void updateCanvas()
    {
        CanvasElement.Children.RemoveRange(0, CanvasElement.Children.Count);

        foreach (MapElementContainer item in mapEditorModel.MapObjects)
        {
            DrawElementOnCanvas(item);   
        }
        //CollisionDetection();
    }
```

And the two event method is:

```
private void CanvasElement_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        updateCanvas();

        MapElementContainer mapObject = new MapElementContainer();

        mapObject.Position = e.GetPosition((Canvas)sender);
        mapObject.MapElement = new ContainerMapObject();
        mapObject.CurrentRotateDegree = mapEditorModel.CurrentRotateDegree;
        mapObject.Shape = BuildShape(mapObject);

        DrawElementOnCanvas(mapObject);   
    }

private void CanvasElement_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MapElementContainer mapObject = new MapElementContainer();

        mapObject.Position = e.GetPosition((Canvas)sender);
        mapObject.MapElement = new ContainerMapObject();
        mapObject.CurrentRotateDegree = mapEditorModel.CurrentRotateDegree;
        mapObject.Shape = BuildShape(mapObject);

        mapEditorModel.MapObjects.Add(mapObject);

        updateCanvas();
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

If I comment all the code in the mouse move function, then I still can't place any element on the canvas at the first click, so maybe is it by design?

Comment: I like your gifs, but show some code for your move event as it's likely the problem is in your code, not just in the fact you bind to the event.

Comment: I edited the answer, as you advised.

Comment: I'm not familiar with drawing on a Canvas, but is it really needed to continuously remove and add all items again in the move eveent? Can't you just update the position?

Comment: Yeah, its a little resource consuming solution, is it could be the root of the problem? On start it will be the first, but its needed to remove it when the mouse leave the canvas, after that it will be placed at the end of it, but how I will know on move that the last one is a placed one (should not be overridden) or just the placeholder? So its not so easy to manage it, because I don't know where it is in the list, so hard to decide when I need to override one in the list or place a new one. Maybe handling in totally individually make the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal code sample which works properly and does not have the problem you mention: it can add shapes as fast as I can click. I suggest you inspect the differences with your code to find the culprit - for one, I don't continuously call updateCanvas or similar as this is not needed.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="AntiqueWhite" Width="1024" Height="768"
          MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" />
</Window>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public class Item
  {
    private readonly Rectangle shape;

    public Item( Canvas canvas )
    {
      shape = new Rectangle { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = Brushes.Black };
      canvas.Children.Add( shape );
      SetPosition( 0.0, 0.0 );
    }

    public void SetPosition( double x, double y )
    {
      Canvas.SetLeft( shape, x );
      Canvas.SetTop( shape, y );
    }
  }

  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private readonly IList<Item> shapes;
    private Item currentMovingShape;

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      shapes = new List<Item>();
      InitMovingShape();
    }

    private void InitMovingShape()
    {
      currentMovingShape = new Item( canvas );
    }

    private void SetMovingShapePosition( MouseEventArgs e )
    {
      var pos = e.GetPosition( canvas );
      currentMovingShape.SetPosition( pos.X, pos.Y );
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
      SetMovingShapePosition( e );
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
      shapes.Add( currentMovingShape );
      InitMovingShape();
      SetMovingShapePosition( e );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, the problem was with the call of `updateCanvas()` method at the start of the mouse move handler.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the MouseDown event is handled in the MapElementContainer class and never reaches CanvasElement? In your second video you always clicked on an empty space. In your first video there is always the MapElementContainer under the mouse.

Comment: MapElementContainer is not exist as a GUI element, under the mouse it is my canvas, which actually has an element drawn at the position there. Or a shape is treated individually from the Canvas? Anyway, its a sub part of the canvas, so the event bubbling reach the canvas.