# How to add node at mouse click location on canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, mouseevent

Right now I an application that lets the user click on a button to browse for a picture to use as a canvas background. I want to make it so if the user clicks somewhere on the canvas, a node is placed at that point. I'm assuming I need to get the mouse coordinates. Is there a simple method to call to place a node at the mouse click location, or do I have to go the route in this link: [WPF - Drawing on canvas with mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037753/wpf-drawing-on-canvas-with-mouse-events) ? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added code that I tried to make the ellipse. It won't work though, and I'm not sure how to use the coordinates of the mouse click with the ellipse. I know for a line it's just .x1 = currentPoint.x etc.

XAML code for canvas:

```
<Canvas Margin="0,45,2,8" x:Name="canvas1">
</Canvas>
```

Code behind for making background of canvas:

```
    private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName;
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selectedFileName));
            canvas1.Background = brush;
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        }
     }

    //This is the method for adding the ellipse.
    private void addNode_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentPoint = new Point();
        if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();

        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

        mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
        ellipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
        ellipse.Width = 10;
        ellipse.Height = 10;

        canvas1.Children.Add(ellipse);

    }
```

Comment: Mouse position is `Mouse.GetPosition()`. Positioning inside `Canvas` is set by using `Canvas.Left`, etc.. What is *node*? Is it a [simple visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx)?

Comment: Oh sorry, by node I meant just a small circle that I'd set the size for and color and all that stuff. I'm using an ellipse right now until I can get it working properly. I'll update post to show the code I tried.

Comment: code here shows how to do that btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075815/c-sharp-wpf-mousemove-event-on-canvas-will-overload-the-mouse-events-so-clic

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to use this in my addNode_MouseDown method:

```
        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas1).X);
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas1).Y);
```

And then I just subscribed to it in the canvas.